# How to make app fully working correctly for autorotation in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios6, autorotate

In iOS6, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated. I tried to use  `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate`  to make app working correctly for autorotation but failed.

this ViewController I don’t want to rotate, but it doesn't work.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is the view controller embedded inside a navigation controller or tabbar controller?

Comment: embedded inside a navigation controller. @phix23

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Figured it out.

**1) subclassed UINavigationController** (the top viewcontroller of the hierarchy will take control of the orientation.)
did set it as self.window.rootViewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

**2) if you don't want view controller rotate**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**3) if you want it to be able to rotate**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

BTW , According to your needs ,another related method :

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering your own question with some nice code examples

Comment: Why are you overwriting `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`? It is deprecated and is never calling

Comment: It works for iOS 5.1 or later.Unless your app's deployment target is 6.0.  @voromax

Comment: Doesn't work. My subclassed UINavigationController never has -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate called.

Comment: Did you set it as self.window.rootViewController? @Zigglzworth

Comment: @voromax "overriding" not "overwriting".

Comment: What exactly are we trying to do when subclassing UINavController?  I have a tab bar-> navbar -> uitablevc -> uivc.  I understand the top hierarchy takes over (tabbarcontroller in my case). I need to force my tablevc portrait & uivc landscape left.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Tab Bar Controller instead of a  Navigation Controller as your root controller, you'll need to similarly subclass UITabBarController.

Also the syntax will be different.  I used the following with success. I then used the above examples with success on the view controllers I wanted to override.  In my case I wanted the main screen to not rotate but I had a FAQ Screen with Movies that I naturally wanted to enable landscape view.  Worked perfectly!    Just note the syntax change to self.modalViewController  (you'll get a compiler warning if you try to use the syntax for a navigation controller.) Hope this helps!

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.modalViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.modalViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```