# How to do orientations in iphone and ipad for ios6?

Tags: ios6.1

How to do orientations in iphone and ipad for ios 6? previous versions showing shouldrotateinterfaceorientation but latest version not showing ?

iam facing problems with orientations for latest version? plz help me?

Comment: You might find [Understanding iOS 6 Interface orientation change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778636/understanding-ios-6-interface-orientation-change) and [How to make app fully working correctly for autorotation in iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662240/how-to-make-app-fully-working-correctly-for-autorotation-in-ios-6) useful.

Comment: Was my answer helpful or you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. In iOS 6 we started using masks.

```
     - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
     {
     return YES;
      }

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
      {
      return    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft   | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
      }
```

You can choose the rotations that you want from what I placed in here and remove the masks that you don't want. Good Luck.