# iOS 8 vs iOS 7 Autorotation

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, ios7.1, uiwindow, autorotate

Here is a simple single view controller app :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
     }


    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
       return YES;
    }

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
   }
```

The outputs are so different in iOS 8.

[image: iOS 8 output]

[image: iOS 7 output]

It's got to do with the difference in UIWindow bounds on iOS 8 vs iOS 7. How do I get iOS 7 like behavior ?

Comment: Is your view controller the root view controller of a window that is the key window?

Comment: Zev, I'm having the exact same problem and I do have a view controller being set as the root view controller. Do you know more about this?

Comment: Another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8) like this has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24153540/947342).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Xcode 6 or iOS 8. After switching to storyboards from xib, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

In IOS8 the list of possible orientations should be in the Info.plist file, the method shouldAutorotate return YES by default.

Take a look on the discussion and documentation below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467576/3330421

UIKit Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations

> When the user changes the device orientation, the system calls this
>   method on the root view controller or the topmost presented view
>   controller that fills the window. If the view controller supports the
>   new orientation, the window and view controller are rotated to the new
>   orientation. This method is only called if the view controller's
>   shouldAutorotate method returns YES.
>
> Override this method to report all of the orientations that the view
>   controller supports. The default values for a view controller's
>   supported interface orientations is set to
>   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and
>   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom.
>
> **The system intersects the view controller's supported orientations
>   with the app's supported orientations (as determined by the Info.plist
>   file or the app delegate's**
>   application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: method) to
>   determine whether to rotate.