# Disable rotation for iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xib

What is the best way of achieving this? I'm using XIBs with universal size classes (same XIB for iphone and ipad) but I want to lock rotation for iphone only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

For versions less than iOS 6:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            return YES;
        }
}
```

For iOS 6+

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: That method is depreciated, unfortunately.

Comment: Edited the answer. Use `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate`

Comment: I made a category on UINavigationController and it works, thanks :) Small problem though, my alertViews still rotate doh.

Comment: The current API for this is `UIDevice.userInterfaceIdiom`.

Answer (score 2):

The list of possible orientations should be in the Info.plist file, you can define distinct values for Ipad and Iphone if you want. Take a look on the discussion below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467576/3330421