# Locking the Viewcontroller to landscape mode, whatever the orientation of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios5

I have one table tableviewController. On clicking one of the cell, the next viewController opens a cam and use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to show video. To support orientations, I have added these lines of codes.

```
  - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
  {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
  //return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
  }
  - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
  duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration     
  {
  [[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] setVideoOrientation:   
  (AVCaptureVideoOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation];
  }
```

But I want to lock my second view controller that shows video in landscape mode only. If the iPhone is in portrait mode, still I want that it will show only landscape mode. Like in some games, orientation is locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy `presenting` the second view controller and set the orientation as landscape in

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897383/667586 for details