# Status bar rotates separated from UIWindow

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have to create application with two `UIWindow` (please, don't ask why). First `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController` supports all orientations. Second one - only portrait and upside down. So application delegate code looks like:

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // part one
    self.windowOne = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.windowOne.rootViewController = [[ViewControllerOne alloc] init]; // supports all orientations
    self.windowOne.rootViewController.view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]] autorelease];

    [self.windowOne makeKeyAndVisible];
    //~part one
    // part two
    self.windowTwo = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.windowTwo.rootViewController = [[ViewControllerTwo alloc] init]; // supports only portrait and upside down
    self.windowTwo.rootViewController.view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]] autorelease];

    [self.windowTwo makeKeyAndVisible];
    //~part two
    return YES;
}
```

If only one of two parts is active (second one is commented) - everything is ok. But if windowOne has become key and visible before `windowTwo`, windowTwo rotates as `ViewControllerTwo` allows, but status bar behaves really weird: it rotates like `windowOne` is key and visible.

Is there any option to make status bar rotating as `ViewControllerTwo` says?

Answer (score 1):

Albeit its a hack to me but what you could *try* is the following:

In your view controllers `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` (for iOS5) or `shouldAutorotate` (as for iOS6) method add the following code line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: interfaceOrientation animated: YES];
```

and test out how the app behaves after that.

to get the interface-orientation in the (new for iOS6) `shouldAutorotate` method do the following:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

I didn't test this all out for myself, but it could work.

(Check out some [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662240/how-to-make-app-fully-working-correctly-for-autorotation-in-ios-6/12662433#12662433) on how to support autorotation under iOS6)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Have tried, but result behavior is not stable. Sometimes, status bar appears on side, not only on top or bottom.

Comment: Hm, what you could try additionally is to put the setStatusBarOrientation code also in your controllers viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear methods. But in the end this all doesn't feel like best-practice to me.

Comment: Issues occurs not on appear/disappear, but on fast device rotation when view is already visible. Seems like described situation is undocumented behavior.