# UIWindow Status Bar Rotation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have an application where I have a use case for two `UIWindow` instances. The first instance runs all normal app interactions, but I need to be able to present a view controller above everything else regardless of what the user is doing in the application, without user interaction.

I have the second window working and presenting fine. In this view controller, I only support portrait mode (though other parts of the app support landscape). I've tried to block rotation using these methods in the `rootViewController` of the window:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
  return [.Portrait]
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
  return false
}
```

That successfully prevents the device from rotating the view controller, but it still allows the status bar to rotate. I'd like to prevent the status bar from rotating as well. I tried adding the following to my `AppDelegate`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
  if let _ = window as? MyTopWindow {
    return [.Portrait]
  } else {
    return .All
  }
}
```

However that hasn't worked either. The status bar still rotates.

I've seen the question below and tried to implement the solution but it's not working for my case: [Status bar rotates separated from UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029858/status-bar-rotates-separated-from-uiwindow)

**Edit**

Here's the code where I create the `UIWindow`:

```
self.callManagementWindow = ActiveCallManagementWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.callManagementWindow.rootViewController = primaryViewController
self.callManagementWindow.hidden = false
self.callManagementWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I should add - if anyone knows of a way I can implement this _without_ using multiple `UIWindow` instances, I'm up for that as well. However, I don't know of any other way to be able to ensure that I can always present a view controller on top of everything else.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're creating and setting up the UIWindows?

Comment: @kpsharp Added the code for that

Comment: Try this: [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
If not resolved , then can you post the code for the remaining UIWindow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time ago I also had issues with two windows and rotation and if I recall right you need to override  `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` and `shouldAutorotate()` in `rootViewController` of first `UIWindow` as well as second one

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do this, but it looks like this is required. I've adjusted my code so when the main `UIWindow` is in the background, those `UIViewControllers` return correct values in `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` that suit the key window.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a try to this in primaryViewController's viewDidAppear :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I setup UIWindow in code, while also specifying Main storyboard
in `Info.plist`

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
```

[image]

The `Main.storyboard` has a simple initial `ViewController` (this ViewController does not specify any orientations)

The solution is removing the `UIMainStoryboardFile` (in `Info.plist` or in General -> Targets -> Deployment Info -> Main Interface)