# Autorotation iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, autorotate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make app fully working correctly for autorotation in iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662240/how-to-make-app-fully-working-correctly-for-autorotation-in-ios-6)

having an issue with autorotation in iOS6. I have added this in App Delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

And added this in View Controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

I still cannot get it to just be portrait, and not landscape! Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have posted an Answer Ryan...

Comment: Similar, but i have more code, and more to go on now really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to set the interface orientation in your App Delegate object. Select in the Project Navigator your Project File. Then select the Target and select Summery. Here you can select the Supported Interface Orientations. This works for the whole project.

Comment: I need it to be different in different views.

Comment: @RyanGittings that's an anti-pattern and is discouraged in iOS 6.

Comment: Well, the majority of the app is data, and i have a view and loads an image, (FGallery), and i want to enable landscape to be able to view pictures landscape...

Comment: you do not net to return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll because it's the default value for iPad. The default for iPhone is UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown. Which device you're support? iPad or iPhone?

Comment: Its an iPhone app... Removed from app delegate. What do i need to put in ViewController? I've unchecked all supported interface orientations in targets...

Comment: in the viewController object you want support automatic interface orientation overwrite the - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate and return yes. If you want specify orientation (for example: only landscapeLeft) overwrite the - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations method. (for example: - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
} )

Comment: Still doesn't work, i dont know what im doing wrong. Added this to bottom of View Controller: `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}` and still no luck, still rotates in simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this only to ViewController:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Delete `shouldAutorotate` and `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:`.

Comment: Done this, hasn't worked. Do i select anything in the targets of the app settings, the Supported Interface Orientation Buttons?

Comment: Yes, you should select orientation which you want to have in your app.