# App for iOS6 shows incorrectly in ios5

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios6, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

Im facing a weird problem in iOS 5. My app was build initially for iOS 6 but for client requirements, I need to add support to iOS 5. The app works in iOS >= 6 perfectly. This is an app developed in landscape, I mean, all the screens are in landscape.
Ok, it compiles in iOS5 and I know the issues about the differences for the rotation stuff between ios5 and ios6 but I dont need rotation in this app, Ive faced with that in other apps, the problem is the simulator turn the screen to landscape, right, but instead of showing the app in landscape.....it shows the app in portrait, its like the screen is in landscape, the layout of the view is correct but its loaded in portrait.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make app fully working correctly for autorotation in iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662240/how-to-make-app-fully-working-correctly-for-autorotation-in-ios-6)

And you should support iOS5, it's not a big deal, iPad 1 and a lot of 3Gs owners are using that

Comment: I will check that! Thank you very much