# force UIViewController to be in Landscape mode iOS7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I've implemented the proper functions, but they don't get triggered? I've tried several solutions here on StackOverFlow, but none of them work. I've tried adding the view to a UINavigationController, also doesn't work.

FakeIDDetailViewController.h:

```
@interface FakeIDDetailViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

FakeIDDetailViewController.m:

```
@interface FakeIDDetailViewController ()

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application     supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: What SO solutions have you tried?  As you say, there are several... and I'd rather not list through them all.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095161/force-landscape-ios-7

Comment: possible duplicate of [In iOS6, trouble forcing ViewController to certain interfaceOrientation when pushed on stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300819/in-ios6-trouble-forcing-viewcontroller-to-certain-interfaceorientation-when-pus)

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491786/force-landscape-viewcontroller-in-ios-7/22491787#22491787

Comment: @Jim Clermonts  you should accept an answer if one of them was helpful

Answer (score 4):

If you are pushing a view controller to a stack of other view controllers in a navigation controller, requiring landscape only will not work well. You should display the landscape-constraint view controller modally.

See my answer here for an example project:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022631/983912

Answer (score 3):

For a navigation controller interface, forcing an orientation is not supported by the framework. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301322/341994

For a workaround (not very good), see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16379515/341994

However, forcing an orientation works fine for a presented view controller.