# Rotate an iOS App ONLY When Playing a Video in WebKit?

Tags: ios, webkit, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an iOS 7 app, and I don't want the whole interface to be landscape, but when a user plays a video I want it to play in landscape. I don't have many view controllers, so I'm fine implementing something in each individual controller.

Comment: be sure to provide some example code so people will be more able to help you

Answer (score 0):

You could force the view into landscape when a video is playing, then after it has finished, force the app into portrait again.

Check this out: [force landscape ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095161/force-landscape-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

Add this category somewhere:

```
@interface UINavigationController (rotation)

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (rotation)

#pragma mark - Rotation

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

// ios4 and ios5
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```