# Change interface orientation when back button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

My app accepts only portrait orientation, except for `MPMoviePlayerController`, which I want to allow user to change orientation.

So, I subclassed `UINavigationController` and added the following code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([[[self.viewControllers lastObject] presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

It works great, allowing only my `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to change orientation. The problem is that when user is in landscape orientation and presses the `done` button or playback ends, it pops the `moviePlayer` and goes back to the presentingViewController, but on landscape mode, causing a crash, since that view is not made for landscape orientation.

I tried a few things to change back to `Portrait` but had no luck. I'm using storyboards, if that makes any difference. I would like to change the orientation back to portrait on `viewWillAppear`, or maybe getting the `done`button press and change the orientation there.

UPDATE:

Here is the updated code in my `UINavigationController`subclass:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[[self.viewControllers lastObject] presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Now, if I do things in the following order from the view with the Play `button`.

1. Rotate the device. (it calls the method but screen doesn't rotate since it is not `MPMoviePlayerController` class)
2. Press the play `button`. (It presents the player already on landscape mode).
3. Press the back button. (It pops the player and correctly shows the view on portrait mode)

Now, if I change the order to:

1. Press the play button. (holding the device on the regular portrait position).
2. Rotate the device. (it rotates the movie player correctly showing the video).
3. Press the back button. (it pops the player, but this time, the view is in landscape mode, which is not the expected behavior)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution here on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24259601/3116306).

On button click, I added a notification and then on done button click I used the below code to change orientation. I kept the `UINavigationController` subclass as in my question to allow the change of orientation when movie starts playing.

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {        
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.player.moviePlayer];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/crzu6yrwt35tgej/flexao.mp4"];        
    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player]; // presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];
}

-(void)moviePlaybackDidFinish
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working configuration for your problem, as far as I understand from your question.

You need a subclass of UINavigationController as you already have, but with the following code:

The .h file:

```
@interface EECNavigationController : UINavigationController

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL landscapeDisallowed;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
#import "EECNavigationController.h"

@implementation EECNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if( !_landscapeDisallowed ) {
        // for iPhone, you could also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Now, in the view controllers that will be under this navigation controller that you want to be just portrait you just need to set the "landscapeDisallowed" to YES in the viewDidLoad method, like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ((EECNavigationController *)self.navigationController).landscapeDisallowed = YES;
}
```

And override the following methods like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The views that can be presented in landscape mode just need to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ((EECNavigationController *)self.navigationController).landscapeDisallowed = NO;
}
```

It works for me, hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good code, but it doesn't solve my problem. It correctly defines which views are allowed for each orientation, although, when I go to a view that is `landscapeDisallowed = NO`, change orientation and pop that view in landscape mode, it shows the previous view in landscape mode, even that being `landscapeDisallowed = YES;`. The expected behavior is for it to manually switch the orientation to portrait.

Comment: It seems that there's a better response for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662240/how-to-make-app-fully-working-correctly-for-autorotation-in-ios-6

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


       [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}
- (void)updateLayoutForNewOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        // Portrait view

        if(iPhone5)

        {
        }else{

        }

        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
        {

        }


    }

    else
    {
        // Landscape view

        if(iPhone5)

        {


        }else{
            float SystemVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
            if(SystemVersion>=7.0f)
            {


            }else{

            }
        }

        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
        {
            if(iPhone5)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }


    }
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}
```

**Hope this will help**

Comment: Well, this code gets the current orientation, but it doesn't actually change the orientation back to portrait, right? I don't want to update my layout according to the orientation, but indeed change the orientation to fit my layout.